# Scroll de un div a otro div en angular

Tags: html, angular

hola tengo un boton al cual quiero que al momento de hacerle click sobre este se haga scroll hacia un div que tengo mas abajo

```
    <div class="barra_ver">
      <input type="button" name="bajar"  scrollTo="sectionB" >
    </div>
```

el boton esta dentro de un div y el div al que quiero llegar haciendo scroll es el sigueinte:

```
        <div class="com_fun" id="sectionB" >
      <h1> usted esta aqui </h1>
    </div>
```

como puedo resolver esto en angular

Answer (score 2):

Puedes agregar el siguiente código:

Declaramos el module de Angular:

```
var angularApp = angular.module("angularApp", []);
```

Realizamos un servicio que se encargue de realizar el scroll hasta tu elemento con el id "**SectionB**":

```
angularApp.service('scrollService', function ($location, $anchorScroll) {
    this.scrollEnd = function () {
        $location.hash("sectionB");
        $anchorScroll();
    };
});
```

Realizamos un controller y mandamos a llamar nuestro servicio:

```
angularApp.controller("scrollController", function ($scope, scrollService) {
    $scope.scrollToHash = function () {
        scrollService.scrollEnd();
    };
});
```

Toma en cuenta que debes mandar a llamar el controller desde tu html y tu botón debe estar dentro. Tampoco olvides mandar a llamar `ng-click="scrollToHash()"` en el botón.

Espero sea de ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: pasarle un parámetro a la function estaría bien para hacerlo mas universal no?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo mediante `jquery`, agrega a tu boton una clase asi.

```
<div class="barra_ver">
   <input type="button" name="bajar" class="btn-scroll">
</div>
```

Ya que le tienes un `id` al `div` que quieres llegar haces una simple funcion en `jquery` donde primero recoges la posicion de tu `div` en la pagina

```
var sectionB = $('#sectionB').offset().top;
```

y luego

```
 $('#btn-scroll').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: sectionB
   }, 500);

 });
```

Asi cuando le tu boton dispare el evento `click` te llevara a la seccion que deseas

Comment: Mezclar jQuery y Angular no es, en general, una buena idea

Comment: @PabloLozano, no lo sabia hermano aun no trabajo con angular. Pero gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar puro HTML para resolverlo, disfrazando un enlace como botón:

```css
.largo {
 width: 200px;
 height: 1600px;
 background: lightgray;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-color: #007bff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#abajo">Pulsa para bajar</a>
<div class="largo">div largo para provocar scroll</div>
<span id="abajo">Has llegado</span>
```

En mi ejemplo he puesto yo los CSS, pero si usas bootstrap es tan sencillo como aplicar la clase "btn" al elemento `<a>`:

```
<a class="btn">Delete</a>
```

Si usas material sería algo como

```
<a class="mc-button mc-button-text">Pulsa para bajar </a>
```